# How to conduct blackbox testing on an AJAX application?

Tags: java, .net, javascript, ajax, testing

What's the best, crossplatform way to perform blackbox tests on AJAX web applications?

Ideally, the solution should have the following attributes:

- Able to integrate into a continuous integration build loop
- Cross platform so I you can run it on Windows laptops and Linux continuous integration servers
- Easy way to script the interactions
- Free-as-in-freedom so you can adapt it into your tool chain if necessary

I've looked into HttpUnit but I'm not conviced it can handle AJAX-heavy websites.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Selenium might be what you're looking for: http://selenium.openqa.org/

It allows you to script actions and evaluate the results. It's open-source (Apache 2.0), cross platform, and has nice tools.

Answer (score 3):

I have used Selenium for exactly this task, but found it to be brittle.

Check out this talk by two Googlers: [Does my button look big in this? Building testable AJAX applications](http://video.google.com/videoplay?docid=4378663232897374824)

They isolate the testable javascript (non DOM-interaction) and test that using the Rhino javascript engine.